# Converting Delphi 2007 string encryption routine to Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe

We have a Delphi 2007 routine used to encrypt passwords in a table. The routine was originally grabbed from a CompuServe post a decade or more ago, and a significant amount of data encrypted with this routine exists.

The heart of the original routine is this:

```
chr(ord(Str[I]) xor not(ord(Id[I mod length(Id) + 1])));
```

I knew the conversion to Delphi XE would be problematic because of Unicode, so I broke that code out into a function that displays each step of the calculations in a memo:

```
function TfrmMain.EncodeDecode(AString: string): string;
const
  Hash: string = '^%12h2DBC3f41~~#6093fn7mY7eujEhbFD3DZ|R9aSDVvUY@dk79*7a-|-  Q';
var
  I: Integer;
  IMod: Integer;
  HMod: Char;
  OMod: Integer;
  AStrI: Char;
  OStrI: Integer;
  ResultStr: string;
  XOrNot: Integer;
  ChrXN: AnsiChar;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add ('AStrI' + TAB + 'IMod' + TAB + 'HMod' +
    TAB + 'OMod' + TAB + 'OStrI' + TAB + 'XOrNot' + TAB + 'ChrXN');

  for I := 1 to Length (AString) do
  begin
    IMod := I mod Length (Hash) + 1;
    HMod := Hash [IMod];
    OMod := Ord (HMod);
    AStrI := AString[I];
    OStrI := Ord (AStrI);  // This is where things go south
    XOrNot := OStrI xor not OMod;
    ChrXN := AnsiChar (XOrNot);
    ResultStr := ResultStr + ChrXN;

    Memo1.Lines.Add (AStrI  + TAB +
      IntToStr (IMod)   + TAB +
      HMod              + TAB +
      IntToStr (OMod)   + TAB +
      IntToStr (OStrI)  + TAB +
      IntToStr (XOrNot) + TAB +
      ChrXN);
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add (ResultStr);
  Result := ResultStr;
end;
```

Like ROT13, the same routine is used to both encrypt and decrypt. If I feed it a string like 'ABCDEFGHI', the Delphi 2007 version can take the resulting encrypted string, run it through the same routine, and get back the original string. The version in Delphi XE, however, doesn't *quite* work. I've made some tweaks (included above) to improve it, but on the OstrI step it falls apart. I think it has something to do with performing an Ord on a (Wide) Char, but that's the closest I can get.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

---

Edited

Here is the original Delphi 2007 code:

```
function EncodeDecode(Str: string): string;
const
  Id: string = '^%12h2DBC3f41~~#6093fn7mY7eujEhbFD3DZ|R9aSDVvUY@dk79*7a-|-  Q';
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to Length (Str) do
    Str[I] := chr (ord (Str[I]) xor not (ord (Id[I mod Length (Id) + 1])));
  Result := Str;
end;
```

We actually have to convert this not only to Delphi XE for new versions of our existing software, but also to C# for a new web-based front end.

Comment: To put it more succinctly: the function is an *involution* (= *its own inverse*).

Comment: I haven't studied the code above in detail, but I see you are mixing `string` and `AnsiString` (and `char` and `AnsiChar`), which generally isn't great when dealing with the raw, binary, data. But perhaps you are aware of this and is only doing things the right way?

Comment: Instead of posting your code that doesn't work, could you just post the D2007 code and one of use will be able to show you how to port it to XE.

Comment: Original post edited to include the starting D2007 code. Thanks @DavidHeffernan and good luck :-)

Comment: @Eric: You sure know how to make things complicated! ;)

Comment: @Andreas: Well, yeah - in my defense, though, what I was doing was trying to really understand each discrete step of the function because my next task is to convert it to C#, at which I'm a noob. So this overdone approach is to show me precisely where I'm screwing up :-)

Comment: @Eric Do you want any help with the C#?! If I were you I would stick with the Delphi code and convert it so that it was used on `array of byte` rather than strings. C# doesn't have an equivalent to AnsiChar and AnsiString. Once I had a Delphi `array of byte` in place I'd flip to C# `byte[]`. That bit should be trivial.

Comment: @David I may well need help with the C#, but I'd like to give it another whirl on my own first. Even if I can't figure it out, I'll probably learn several things along the way, so the exercise won't be wasted in any case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple approach is, in essence, as follows:

1. Start with the Delphi 2007 code.
2. Change `string` to `AnsiString`.
3. Change `Char` to `AnsiChar`.
4. Possibly change `Chr()` to `AnsiChar()`.

There may be more nuances to your code. Ideally I'd like to see the original Delphi 2007 version of the code.

---

Having posted the original code, I think you should can use this routine in XE:

```
function EncodeDecode(const Str: AnsiString): AnsiString;
const
  Id: AnsiString = '^%12h2DBC3f41~~#6093fn7mY7eujEhbFD3DZ|R9aSDVvUY@dk79*7a-|-  Q';
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := Str;
  for I := 1 to Length(Result) do
    Result[I] := AnsiChar(ord(Result[I]) xor not (ord(Id[I mod Length (Id) + 1])));
end;
```

Note that I changed the code to take input as a `const` string and to use `Result` as the working buffer. This is not necessary for your ANSI/Unicode needs, but feels more natural to me!

Comment: This is *always* a way of making pre-Unicode Delphi code work in a modern version of Delphi. The only (and obvious) downside is that you do not gain Unicode support.

Comment: @Andreas I guess it's OK in this case for OP since OP has data locked in files that is limited to ANSI.

Comment: Wow, I was way over-thinking the problem. Thank you David for the quick answer!

Comment: @David: to take your suggestion a step further, I would suggest changing the input/output values from `AnsiString` to `RawByteString`. Prior to D2009, `AnsiString` did not really make any assumptions about the codepage used to encode the characters. In D2009 onwards, it does, whereas `RawByteString` inherits the codepage of whatever Ansi string is passed to it.

Comment: @Remy I figured codepages wouldn't be an issue when using the AnsiString as a byte buffer. But I'm no expert on such nuances. What problems could arise from using AnsiString rather than RawBytesString?

Comment: @David: starting in D2009, `AnsiString` (aka `AnsiString(0)` now) has an associated codepage stored within its character data.  Whenever an `AnsiString(N)` is assigned to an `AnsiString(M)` (where `N` and `M` are codepages, and `N <> M` - `RawByteString` is `AnsiString($FFFF)`, `UTF8String` is `AnsiString(65001)`, etc), or to/from a `UnicodeString` or `WideString`, an implicit data conversion occuring using the codepage that is inside the Ansi data.  That can corrupt your data if you are not careful.  `AnsiString` is not a suitable choice for binary data anymore.  Use `TBytes` or `TStream`

Comment: @Remy I think I understand. But the problem is that that the user presumably wants a string with an associated code page.  The user is going to want to display the string. Since base64 uses the ASCII range then there's no possible loss of information, I think. If the decode emits non-ASCII characters then surely the user really needs `AnsiString(CodePageUsedToEncodeTheData)` rather than `RawByteString`.

Comment: @David: it is true that base64 itself is safe in any codepage, since it only uses ASCII.  But when the base64 is decoded into binary data, there is a possibility for data loss if the binary is stored in an `AnsiString` or `RawByteString`, and then is passed around.  Fortunately, you can use `SetCodePage()` to store a codepage value in a `RawByteString` at runtime.  You cannot do that with an `AnsiString` (without using type-casts, anyway, which is not recommended).